# Getting Check Box Values and Checking if They are in an Array

Tags: javascript

So, essentially, what I would like to do is to grab all of the check boxes with name="chkOptions", loop through them, and then see if any of the values that are in the "toppingCodes" Array match with a value that has been assigned in the HTML check boxes.

So far, for my JS, I have looped through all of the check boxes, but I am stumped on how to see if any of the values given to the checkbox inputs match any in my "toppingCodes" Array.

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("chkOptions");
let toppingCodes = ["XCHE", "XSCE", "OLIV", "ANCH"];
//Loop through check boxes
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    //Search for checkbox value in toppingCodes
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Options:</div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkOptions" id="chkExtraCheese"  value="XCHE">Extra Cheese
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkOptions" id="chkExtraSauce" value="XSCE">Extra Sauce
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkOptions" id="chkOlives" value="OLIV">Olives
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkOptions" id="chkAnchovies" value="ANCH">Anchovies
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic solution: loop through the array and compare the values.

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < toppingCodes; j++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].value === toppingCodes[j]) {
      // Yay, it matches
      break; // No reason to keep looping over `toppingCodes`
    }
  }
}
```

Using built-in methods:

```
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  if (toppingCodes.indexOf(checkboxes[i].value) >= 0) {
    // Yay, it matches
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others above have mentioned Array.indexOf is what you're looking for. If the returned value is greater than -1 then it's true.

I made a JSFiddle for you here to further illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/mhrgfwL1/5/

```
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("chkOptions");
let toppingCodes = ["XCHE", "XSCE", "OLIV", "ANCH"];
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const isInArray = function(val) {
    return toppingCodes.indexOf(val) > -1;
};

[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
  el.onchange = function(e) {
    if (el.checked) {
        if (isInArray(el.value)) alert(`${el.value} is in the array!`)
    }
  }
});
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.filter` function
This function applies a filter to certain array so, if you want to check if the checkbox value is inside of `toppingCodes` array, you can do this:

```
var ocurrences = checkboxes.filter(function(checkbox){
     return toppingCodes.indexOf(checkbox.value) > -1;
});
if(ocurrences > 0)
{
     //the value is inside toppingCodes array
}
```